# How project Lombok in java works and is that possible in .net using attributes?

Tags: java, .net, lombok

Project [Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/) makes it trivial to implement the boilerplate code in the classes. Is that possible with .NET attributes? Is any .net port there?

Comment: Doesn't .Net already have properties?

Comment: @Rlmeq yes but see this example http://projectlombok.org/features/Data.html. It almost looks like magic with a single attribute

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well in Lombok a Java class might look like this

```
import lombok.Data;

@Data public class Cart {
  private int id;
  private DateTime created;
  private int items;
  private int status;
}
```

While in C# the same class would look like this

```
public class Cart {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public DateTime Created { get; set; }
  public int Items { get; set; }
  public int Status { get; set; }
}
```

So C# (3.0 in this example) gets rather close without any other libraries, but as you start adding "final" to some properties the magic "auto constructor" part of Lombok really shines.  As for a .Net alternative, as I understand it the .Net annotations don't provide the ability to intercept the byte code before it goes to the compiler (what Lombok uses to such great effect), so your options are limited to some template system + a build script like nAnt.  This would be a mess to maintain.

Comment: You can't intercept byte code generation but there are some pretty sophisticated libraries for parsing the final assemblies. You could use public fields in the code and then have a post-build step rewrite all involved assemblies to use the auto-generated properties. But you won't be able to achieve everything Lombok does with this technique. Better use something like T4 (code generation) and partial classes.

Comment: @Jason your C# code is not really equivalent to the Java code: equals and hashCode are missing. Lombok generates that as well.

Comment: That's true. It's been quite some time since I wrote that answer. I've learned a lot more since then but I think my point still holds. That Lombok does a lot automatically and the method it uses is (still) unique to Java.

Comment: Your C# code is equivalent to Lombok's `@Getter @Setter` annotations, but `@Data` is more than this. `@Data` is a convenient shortcut annotation that bundles the features of `@ToString`, `@EqualsAndHashCode`, `@Getter` / `@Setter` and `@RequiredArgsConstructor` together.

Comment: Furthermore, Lombok has constructor generators for things like `@AllArgsConstructor`, `@RequiredArgsConstructor`, and `@NoArgsConstructor` which are insanely useful at eliminating noise in classes. Wish we had this for .NET

Comment: I think the missing point is that real data classes offer equality comparison by design along with automatically implemented hash code & ToString. This is why simple properties existence in C# is not enough. Please look at the details of Kotlin's data classes to feel the difference.

Comment: Now show us what the equivalent to `@Delegate` looks like..

Answer (score 9):

Now there is a .NET port! Check out [Lombok.NET](https://github.com/CollinAlpert/Lombok.NET).

Disclaimer: I am the author of this library.

Comment: this is freaking amazing. thanks for the contribution!

Comment: You're very welcome. Feel free to drop an issue if you have any more requirements.

Comment: @CollinAlpert I am a Java developer for over a decade now, but I do try out and sometimes even work with a lot of other languages, including C#. This library of yours is amazing. I have not used it yet, but I have read the GitHub page. I wish GitHub would have a way to at least say thank you! Such a pretty enhancement for C# in my opinion.

Comment: @Voronin Thanks so much for your feedback, it means a lot. Feel free to star the repository to say 'thank you' :)

Answer (score 0):

I would say:

```
public class Cart {
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public DateTime Created { get; set; }
   public int Items { get; set; }
   public int Status { get; set; }
}
var cart = new Cart
{
   Id = 10,
   DateTime = DateTimeNow,
   ....
};
```

Dont need any builder per se. Just use c# object initializer? That said, it does not hide any implementation stuff. So if you would like to put some "factoring" of more complex init data to your init, you can hide that in the builder, but not directly in the object initializer. You must put that somewhere in the getter, or a helper class. The Lombok java generator does not either by the way.
And the object initializer does not do any fluent stuff either, like .id(..).name() etc.

Comment: The c# object initializer is nice, but for DI containers a (generated) constructor is kind of required.