# C# alternative for ProjectLombok - "Immutable setter"

Tags: c#, immutability, setter, lombok

Is there some C# alternative for ProjectLombok [@With](https://projectlombok.org/features/With) annotation?

I would like to use some convenient method to prepare test data sets without much coding.

Comment: Have you seen the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959646/how-project-lombok-in-java-works-and-is-that-possible-in-net-using-attributes) about .NET and lombok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# 9 supports `record` for that purpose.
There is no out of the box solution in the earlier versions, so you may want to use 3rd party libraries. E.g. https://github.com/ababik/Remute

It also can be handy if you have to deal with nested records in C# 9.

```
record Address(string Street, string State);
record Person(string FirstName, string LastName, Address Address);
var person1 = new Person(...);
var person2 = person.With(x => x.Address.Street, "new street");
```

Comment: That is something I was looking for! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

C# 9 will support this natively without any external libraries or IL weaving.

The new feature named "records" support a sub-feature called "with-expressions" which do exactly this:

```
Person brother = person with { FirstName = "Paul" };
```

This line creates a new object from the `person` variable, with all the very same data but with the `FirstName` set to specified value.

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9) with a better explanation.